# Stream AVI file from memory using IIS/Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have some AVI files on disk but they are encrypted. I'm wondering if there is a way I can decrypt them and stream them to the browser (using `MemoryStream` or something similar) without having to write any files?

I know there is [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx) but I'm using a Vista machine and Windows Media Services will only install in Windows Server 2003 and 2008.

Is there a way to accomplish this without too much trouble or is Media Services/Windows Server the only way to go? And if there is, would I use something like a custom `IHttpHandler` (.ashx file)?

---

**Edit:**

I have decided to use a custom `IHttpHandler`. What basic code would I need to have the video play?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want to use a `MemoryStream` for video.  Assuming you can create a `CryptoStream` (found in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace) over the encrypted AVI file you should be able to just pump a `Read` from that to a `Write` on the `Response.OutputStream` in a `IHttpHandler`.  Something like:-

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[65556];  // adjust the buffer size as yo prefer.
 CryptoStream inStream = YourFunctionToDecryptAVI(aviFilePath);
 int bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 65556); 
 while (bytesRead != 0)
 {
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
    bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 65556);
    if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected) break;
 }
 Response.Close();  //see edit note.
```

Make sure you turn off response buffer and specify a content type.

**Edit**:

Ordinarily I hate calling close, it seems so draconian.  However whilst chunked encoding shouldn't require it, in the case of streamed video it may be that the client doesn't like it.  Also with large data transfers closing the connection is not really big deal.

Comment: When I tried it, Media Player fails with a "could not connect to server" error

Comment: If you write the data that way, be sure to Clear() the Response first, and then set its BufferOutput property to False.  That will cause ASP.NET to output a "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" HTTP header, so the data is truely streaming.

Comment: I cleared the Response and set BufferOutput to false. Windows Media Player stays stuck with an "Opening media..." status

Comment: @Remy: I tend not to use .Clear in a handler, its belts and braces but if it really did anything then something is wrong already.

Comment: @mcjabberz:  Potentially you need to include a Response.Close() at the end of streaming.  Without any Content-Length (and with buffering off) it may be that the client will indefinitely wait for content.

Comment: Here is <a href="http://pastebin.com/m16846c15">my exact code</a>. I'm still running into the same issue with Media Player getting stuck  

PS: Thank you all for the help!!!

Comment: You don't appear to be decrypting in that chunk of code?  How large is the AVI?  Try using a small avi restire buffering to true and remove the close.  This checks the basic functionality.